# How to reuse external javascript files in Grails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I created a simple javascript file and placed it inside web-app/js and named it util.js

It contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // adds a space after 3rd digit/letter of postal code
    $('#postalCode').keyup(function() {
        var postalCodeValue = this.value;
        var postalCodeLength = postalCodeValue.length;

        if(postalCodeLength == 3){
            this.value = postalCodeValue + " ";
        }
    });
});
```

It's very simple code, and I attached it on main.gsp so that I don't have to keep on importing it every single time.

```
...
<div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;" /></div>
    <g:javascript library="application" />
    <g:javascript library="util" />
    <r:layoutResources />
...
```

Now, there are two forms using it(Form1 and Form2).
They belong on different gsp files.
Both Form1 and Form2 have a textfield that has the same id "#postalCode".

```
<g:textField name="postalCode" maxlength="7" id="postalCode" pattern="([A-Z]|[a-z])[0-9]([A-Z]|[a-z]) [0-9]([A-Z]|[a-z])[0-9]" required="" value="${fosterHomeInstance?.postalCode}"/>
```

Thing is, the util.js works on Form1, but the odd thing is, it does not work on Form2. Given that they have the same id, and placed the code `<g:javascript library="util" />` inside main.gsp then in theory, they should work right? Hmm.. It's pretty strange. I right click on Form2 to view the source code, util.js is certainly there. I can't really think of reasons why it shouldn't work. I wanted it to work on both forms because I don't want to rewrite the same code all over again.

PS: I tried changing the id to class = "postalCode" and changed the $('#postalCode')... to $('.postalCode') but still didn't work. I also added an onClick trigger on the postal code textfield where on click an alert will appear(whose code was from util.js) to test if util.js was being read, it worked, but it still doesn't solve the problem. I am baffled. I could simply rewrite it to onKeyUp and add a function the old javascript fashion but I could be missing something here, so I'd like to hear from you guys first. :'(

Comment: when you view the source of the page, and you see the util.js is there i think grails has done its job, now why it doesnt work is a pure javascript issue. See in firebug console if there are any errors or so. or else you can debug the script in firebug.

Comment: It's rather weird because it works on form1 but it doesn't work on form2. I haven't exactly tried debugging javascript in the firebug console, but I'll try it now. :) And yes, both form1 and form2 has util.js on view source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding console.log("Descriptive text") in places throughout your main JavaScript function for debugging purposes. That will allow you to see how far you're getting into JavaScript before it quits working. It may well be that some of the JavaScript is executing as you expect, but other parts aren't. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("Document is ready");
  $('#postalCode').keyup(function(){
    console.log("Keyup function started.");
    var postalCodeValue = this.value;
    var postalCodeLength = postalCodeValue.length;
    console.log("Postal Code Value is: " + postalCodeValue);
    console.log("Postal Code Length is: " + postalCodeLength);

    if(postalCodeLength == 3){
        console.log("The postal code length is exactly 3.");
        this.value = postalCodeValue + " "
    }
}); });
```

Notably, Internet Explorer doesn't have console turned on by default, so you'll want to either remove these lines before publishing your site for public consumption, or check the browser and define console as something else if the browser is IE.

You can open the JS console in Chrome with CTRL+SHIFT+J. See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers for other methods on opening it.